# How to insert a comment in the middle of a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a long and complicated SQL statement, in the middle of it, I want to insert a comment.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE Column1 IN ('Code1' --Comment here--, 'Code2' --Comment here--)
```

Please notice how the part after 'Code1' --Comment here-- is greyed out. That's because the whole line after -- is considered a comment.

Currently I have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE Column1 ='Code1' --Comment here--
   OR Column1 ='Code2' --Comment here--
```

I wonder if anyone has a better way to write this. Thanks..

Comment: Use `/* . . . */`.  Those are the delimited comment characters recognized by SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL,

```
mysql> SELECT 1 /* this is an in-line comment */ + 1;
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

Comment: Tagged as SQL Server, but is still correct if you remove the command line `mysql>`

Answer (score 3):

Use inline comments for this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE Column1 IN ('Code1' /*Comment here*/, 'Code2' /*Comment here*/)
```

Comment: I'm aware of the multi-line comment. Just never thought I would use it to take care of a one-liner issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE Column1 IN ('Code1' /* CODE1 */, 'Code2' /* CODE2 */)
```

I will add that this type of embedded comment is likely to make the code *harder* to follow rather than easier.  One such comment is probably okay, but if you want to include comments on all values, I would go with the multi-line version in your question.

Normally, by the way, the `/* . . . */` is used for multi-line comments or to quickly comment out a block of code.

Comment: Thanks for the additional advice :)